# Can a wireless router stream content without an Internet connection?

Tags: router

I am looking to stream some content to a tablet from a usb hard drive attached to a wireless router that has no internet connection. Is this possible? I would like to use this setup in my car so my kids can listen to music or watch a movie on this tablet. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a DLNA enabled MiFi (3/3.5/4G to WLAN) router? Some can take a SD card and stream the media on the card. Plus, you would have internet wherever you have connectivity. And it's much smaller and comes with a battery already.

Answer (score 2):

the answer is yes - probably.

It depends on your model of router as to what it can stream - but in the event that no internet connection is present, all of your devices will still be able to talk to eachother.

When devices join your wireless network, they are given an IP address and this address is their place on your internal network.  The only real difference between this setup with and without a working internet connection is their ability to get to "stuff" outside of your network.. but since all your "stuff" (tablet, hard drive, laptops etc) are all inside your network - then the availability of an internet connection should be irrelevant.

An easy test for this is to set it up in your house, then simply unplug the internet cable from the router (the one that goes to your phone line or wallbox) and see if it still works and does what you need it to.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ofcourse it can.

There is no technical reason why you could not stream some data from a local source (the USB disk) without having some connection to an external source(s).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there should be no problem with this.  The router does not need an internet connection create a wireless network.  You may have to go into the router options and set it to share the hard drive but if the router has a USB port, chances are its default is most likely to share HD's on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of usb you get you could share content straight from the router(given the router has that support also). They also offer usb devices that can connect wireless.

Another cool option would be to setup your own personal network. You could then use a host device to stream the content through the car. One affordable option as a host is a raspberry pi. I always love raspberry pi projects. It is relatively powerful for the price. I will include a link below with the amazon rasberry pi 2b. There is also a link below with the tutorial on how to turn the pi into a media server. You can also go for any low power computer like the intel pc stick, but those options are going to bring up the price quite a bit.

The tutorial is fairly straight forward. I would recommend getting a small screen and handheld keyboard for the pi to make sure everything is good to go in the car. The worst thing would be it failing on you mid-road trip and not being able to use it until you get somewhere with a screen.

Tutorial:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=56149

PI:
[http://www.amazon.com/Raspberry-Pi-Model-Project-Board/dp/B00T2U7R7I/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1449755991&sr=8-2&keywords=raspberry+pi+zero](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00T2U7R7I)

Good Luck!

Comment: No problem, the cool thing about the pi is that you can also setup a backup camera and other features with it. I know with kids the backup camera has been an incredible feature!