# Using an router that has no actual internet as a local internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I was wondering how to setup an old router as a local host type deal router. So basically I was doing some tests on my computer, I connected to my Wi-Fi using netsh command on windows, I then found even though I dont have internet anymore as I havent payed my bill, I was about to connect to the router on port 23 through telnet and ping it as well. I was wondering, if I can use it to keep all my devices in the house connected? Like one of my goals in mind is to use it to connect to my Wifi-Direct TV (The wifi direct sucks on that I was wondering if I could setup a local type connection to amplify it.) Basically I want to create a local network with that old router. Is this possible?

Some questions related but not the same as to what I am asking I checked are listed here....

[Can a wireless router stream content without an Internet connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/1011629/can-a-wireless-router-stream-content-without-an-internet-connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First an assumption on my side: I assume that with "local internet connection" you meant "local network connection". In which case: Yes, that is what you would use a a router for.

Most 'SOHO-routers' are multiple devices in one, e.g. router, DHCP server, firewall, wireless access point, wired Ethernet switch, ...

And this is all you need. Without a connection from the router to the your ISP (and from there to the rest of the Internet) you can still use it for basic connections (wired and wireless), if it has a DHCP server it will still hand out DHCP leases. Almost everything will still work.

The only two things which you will lack are:

1. Access to the Internet (well, duh! :) )
2. Access to nameservers on the Internet. You will either need to use IP addresses, run your own local nameserver, use netBIOS names or similar.

Comment: Awesome thank you. So I will for instance be able to ping my other devices? Or access their IP's?

Comment: Yes. Something like `ping 192.168.1.101` or similar should just work. (Adjust for the correct IPs, and note that I used an IP to ping, not a name).

Comment: Do I need to connect a cable to LAN or WLAN? (I am not familar with hardware, I am just familar with network programming and general programming)

Comment: Alright, so how to I set local name servers? Using IP is not an issue, so I dont have a problem with it.

Comment: Wait I dont need my cable connected right? Cause I did not have the cables in the router other than the power cable (duh) when I pinged it.

Comment: So would file transfer and stuff between machines be possible? Or using the router for any type of file transfer?

Comment: There are many local DNS servers programs. Mostly it just comes down to choose one, download it (from a place with Internet), move to something which is usually turned on (e.g. a server, a NAS, maybe the router if it has OpenWRT, Tomato or similar), install and configure.  And yes, that is a very generiuc answer, bit without knowing which devices you have and which Operating systems they run it will just have to do.

Comment: So what about file transfer and strengthening my Wi-Fi direct and screen mirroring?

Comment: Re filetransfers. Ofcourse. No need for the Internet for that. If you use two windows systems with file sharing then just try [start] [run] `\\192.168.1.101\C$` or similar. If Linux with Samba: same-ish. IN most cases sFTP, scp, etc etc all the same.    Re: speed: wired is almost always much faster. Not needed, just much faster.

Comment: I upvoted the answer and chose it as the answer. You have been very helpful and I thank you very much.

Comment: But what if I use Windows to Android?

Comment: Unfortunely I do not have enough reputation here to make public upvotes, but I have accepted the answer.

Comment: Awesome thank you. So as long as they are connected to the router, I can be able to remotely keep the devices connected?

Comment: I dont have any cords plugged into the back, example in the ethernet, or WAN slots, only the power plug, that wont make any difference if I can connect via my computer correct?

Comment: I was also wondering... I have IIS and a website for my company I was wondering, I wanted to access my websites from all my devices to see if it works on multiple platforms, I was wondering, can I use the router to have the browsers access the localhost server

Comment: You should ask that as a different question. Note that HTTP **does** use the werbsite name in its requests and that it will act differently if you access the website based on its IP (it is the odd duck out there with the rest of the internet protocols). Also localhost is local. To access it from different devices you would need its public address (read: anything not 127.0.0.0/8, assuming IPv4).